# How to assign string value for each element in a collection variable to different screen elements in screen flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am getting List from an invocable method in flow. I have created a collection variable to store the values but I am not sure how to assign value of each element in collection to screen elements separately.
For example: myVarCollection has values like {'abc','123','xyz','123'}. I want to assign it to different screen flow fields by using something like myVarCollection[0], myVarCollection[1] and so on..

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  What have you tried so far (use [edit].  You'll need a loop and a counter

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. I tried loop and counter and assigned  each value to different text variables. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct flow support to fetch items from a collection by their index value

If your collections are of reasonable size, you can do the following:

- Create a number variable `iterationIndex` used to count from 0,1, .. n
- Use a Loop element over the collection
- Within the for each element part of the loop, use a multi-branched Decision element that tests for the value of `iterationIndex`.

  - If 0, take current collection loop variable and assign to Screen element A
  - If 1, take current collection loop variable and assign to Screen element B
  - ...
- Using an Assignment element, add 1 to `iterationIndex`
- end loop